# Tab key increases volume in Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I am using ASUS VivoBook together with Fedora 29. Everything works except for a keyboard glitch. Pressing `Tab` increases volume, even though the entry for *Volume up* in Keyboard Shortcuts settings is *Audio raise volume* (fn key). The same happens with `Ctrl+Tab` and backtick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tracking it down it turned out to be hardware issue. Pressing `Tab` actually sent the code for `Volume up`, hence this can't be solved programmatically.

Comment: That's crazy. Hardware is ridiculous :) You may be able to remap it with xkb... there's a question around here somewhere on that in general